# Java Flag -XX:+CompileTheWorld usable for Microbenchmarks

Tags: java, jvm

What is the use of this flag `-XX:+CompileTheWorld`?

I found this flag [here](http://stas-blogspot.blogspot.de/2011/07/most-complete-list-of-xx-options-for.html) where it says that

> Compile all methods in all classes in bootstrap class path (stress test)

Can I except no more compilations at runtime? Or will (profiled) compilations still take place and adjust the code?

Edit:
To solve my XY-Problem: It this flag suitable for Microbenchmarks?

Answer (score 3):

Java 9 is looking at adding `-XX:+AOT` flag (Ahead Of Time compiler).

Note: if you compile in advance, you can't utilize dynamic optimizations and the code you get might be quite a bit slower.

The best option is to run the benchmark code until you are sure the code has warmed up and then time the performance. e.g. this is what JMH does.

In fact if you are writing a micro-benchmark, I highly recommend you use [JMH](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/code-tools/jmh/) first.